# How can i use my debug.exe on another computer with another monitor in fullscreen mode?

Tags: c#, wpf

The monitor on the first pc was 1280 x 1024. I used WindowState Fullscreen.
Now i tried on another computer, another monitor(less Resolution)
and it's fullscreen, but i can see only a little part of my window.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. [See the How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Please provide your XAML code and if you changed any window settings in your normal code, share this one as well. Furthermore go to the designer where you can change the layout of our application, click on the window and normally in your bottom right corner is a properties window, go and search through it if you set anywhere a max/min size for the window or any settings referring to the size and its resizing ability. Show me which of these you have set.

**It should be enough to set it in XAML as:**

```
WindowState="Maximized
```

---

**Create your Release Build in Visual Studio this way:**

On the Toolbar is the MenuItem "Create" (the 5th from the left side) click on it. Then from the bottom the second one "Create Batch" click it. Then a table opens. There should already be your programm in the version debug. Create a new one, now in release state. Click 'create it'.

Now go open your explorer. Go to the path where Visual Studio saves your projects. Open your current project, then there is a folder with the name of your project, open it as well. Now there is a bunch of files and folder, you are supposed to open the "bin" Folder, then "Release" Folder and in there is an `*.exe` with the Name of your project. Use this one instead.

Comment: i'm using WindowState Maximized :/ and using WPF